# Relaxed write, what does it mean?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

> ```
> private static class Node<E> {
>     volatile E item;
>     volatile Node<E> next;
>
>     /**
>      * Constructs a new node.  Uses relaxed write because item can
>      * only be seen after publication via casNext.
>      */
>     Node(E item) {
>         UNSAFE.putObject(this, itemOffset, item);
>     }
> ```

It comes from `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java`

What does it mean, relaxed write?

Comment: This can be related to this: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Consistency_model#/Relaxed_Memory_Consistency_Models. Not sure though.

Comment: I believe its like the opposite of volatile - a write that is not guaranteed to be seen across threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good question. But  the clue to understanding this term lies in ... JDK 9, where `sun.misc.Unsafe` has become (or will become - what is more appropriate to say, see [here](http://mydailyjava.blogspot.ie/2013/12/sunmiscunsafe.html)) public API.

In JDK 9 the corresponding place, which you refers to, is implemented as follows:

```
static final class Node<E> {
    volatile E item;
    volatile Node<E> next;

    /**
     * Constructs a node holding item.  Uses relaxed write because
     * item can only be seen after piggy-backing publication via CAS.
     */
    Node(E item) {
        ITEM.set(this, item);
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `ITEM` is instance of `VarHandle` class which implements similar functionality as `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Now, we can look at this method's [JavaDoc description](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#set-java.lang.Object...-) and find the following:

> Sets the value of a variable to the newValue, with memory semantics of
>   setting as if the variable was declared non-volatile and non-final.
>   Commonly referred to as plain write access.

In other words, we can conclude, that *relaxed write* is the same as *plain write access*. In other words, I believe that [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael)'s commentary above is right:

> ... its like the opposite of volatile - a write that is not guaranteed
>   to be seen across threads.

(see the opposite method `setVolatile` which works as if the variable was declared `volatile`).